# Configure abrt to dump core file without root privileges

Tags: core-dump, abrt

I run my program on a machine for which I do not have root privileges. The core file is supposed to be handled by `abrt`:

```
$ sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e %P %I %h
```

**Now, how can I obtain the core file? It is not located anywhere in my `$HOME`, or in the folder where I ran my program.** I tried many locations such as `/var/spool`, `/var/cache`, `/var/tmp`, etc.

According to the `abrt` documentation I made a configuration file `$HOME/.config/abrt/settings/abrt-applet.conf` containing:

```
AutoreportingEnabled = yes
ProcessUnpackaged = yes
DumpLocation = /path/to/existing/folder
```

(only the second variable is from the documentation, the other two are from other abrt files that do not seem understood here)

**After creating this file, I did get the mention `core dumped` line when my program crashes, which was not the case previously, but no core file appeared.**

Comment: I should mention why I specify "without root privileges". The abrt doc says the variable `DumpLocation` can be set to choose the folder, but this lies in a root-permission file.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, creating the file `abrt-applet.conf` as suggested in the question was the good way to go. Then don't forget to set `ulimit -c unlimited` and restart your session. The core file appeared in the current directory, not in the directory specified by `DumpLocation` though.